# the user input commands and int in one line and how to validate if they put the right command

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

i have set of instruction to users input

- `reverse from [start] count [count]` – this instructs you to reverse a portion of the array – just [count] elements starting at index [start];
- `sort from [start] count [count]` – this instructs you to sort a portion of the array - [count] elements starting at index [start];
- `rollLeft [count] times` – this instructs you to move all elements in the array to the left [count] times. On each roll, the first element is placed at the end of the array;
- `rollRight [count] times` – this instructs you to move all elements in the array to the right [count] times. On each roll, the last element is placed at the beginning of the array;

How can I separate the integers that the user gave me and how to validate it?

Comment: Please provide code you use to get data from user and what data is expected.

Comment: See [ask]. The idea is you tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what result you got.

Comment: input: 
1 2 5 8 7 3 10 4 6 9
reverse from 2 count 4
end
output:
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 5, 10, 6, 4, 9]

Comment: I try to split() but it did not work and also i try to get the number from the string but my problem with that is how can i validate what command hes using also need to check the parameter in the input is valid

Answer (score 0):

If user should input list of integers to be treated according to the set of instructions than you can get what you want with the following code:

```
input_string = input('input integers separated by spaces:\n')
try:
    input_ints = list(map(int, input_string.strip().split()))
    print('your input is', input_ints)
except ValueError:
    print('cannot transform input to list of integers')
else:
    print('processing input...')
    # your code with processing numbers according to the set of instructions
```